# Code to show userform when Tab key is pressed

Tags: excel, vba

I have a small userfom with 3 textboxes in it.
One textbox is for date and other two are for entry.
Date textbox i.e. textbox one is set to be focused.

I have one calendar userform also.

What i want is when i press the tab key button the calendar userform should popout and then i will select the date the useform will close.

My only concern is to pop up the calendar using the tab key.

I have tried other options by clicking on the textbox but my requirement is to pop up calendar with tab key.

Kindly advise how to do it.

Thanks
Salman

Comment: Just handle the tab key in `UserForm_KeyDown`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your userform.open in a sub called OpenForm, then you could use:

```
Application.OnKey "{TAB}", "OpenForm"
```